# Bootstrap carousel align to the center of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a code about bootstrap carousel and it works perfectly however I want to align it on the center of my page. i tried so many different solutions but still no avail. is there any way to align this to the center

```
<div class="container">
  <br>
        <div class = "row">

                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel ">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

</ol>


<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

  <div class="item active">
    <img src="css/pet9.jpg" alt="Chania">

  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="css/pet10.jpg" alt="Chania">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="css/pet8.jpg" alt="Flower" >

  </div>



</div>


<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>

</a>

     </div>
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/khanhvdv/ck5m3sr8/

Comment: i kinda edited the size of my carousel to a lower size that is why it is on the left side of the page. i am satisfied with the size however the position of the carousel is what I want to change to the center of the page

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khanhvdv/ck5m3sr8/2/ it's hard to guess your current problem without looking at you css

Answer (score 1):

You can surround it with the `<center>` tag.